# Correct JSDoc typings for Webpack `cacheGroups` option?

Tags: jsdoc, webpack-5

I have the following code in my **webpack.config.js**:

```
optimization: {
  splitChunks: {
    cacheGroups: buildWebpackCacheGroups(),
  },
},
```

In Webpack 4 I was able to annotate the return type of `buildWebpackCacheGroups` with JSDoc like this:

```
/**
 * @return {Record<string, webpack.Options.CacheGroupsOptions>}
 */
function buildWebpackCacheGroups() {

}
```

I'm now attempting to upgrade to Webpack 5, but `webpack.Options.CacheGroupsOptions` is [no longer available as a type](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/v5.21.2/types.d.ts). So I tried the following:

```
/**
 * @return {Record<string, webpack.Configuration['optimization']['splitChunks']['cacheGroups']>}
 */
function buildWebpackCacheGroups() {

}
```

But it produces this error:

> Property 'cacheGroups' does not exist on type 'false | OptimizationSplitChunksOptions'.

How can I solve this?

Comment: what does your **buildWebpackCacheGroups** function return?